# Debug error app crash server 2008 & windows7 c0000005 c0000096

Tags: .net, debugging, access-violation, crash

I have a problem with running an application (handycafe) in Server 2008 and Windows 7 as server installation.
It works fine in XP and Server 2003. So I used the debugging tools and got the following from windows debugging tools.

```
0:000:x86> g
ModLoad: 765d0000 76630000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 764e0000 765ac000   C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 6cab0000 6cac9000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\olepro32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`73380000 00000000`733a1000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76640000 00000000`76685000   C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`031d0000 00000000`032e9000   C:\Program Files\handyCafe\Server\resources\cmanres.dll
(ff0.e9c): Unknown exception - code 0eedfade (first chance)
(ff0.e9c): Unknown exception - code c0000096 (first chance)
(ff0.e9c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
00000000 ??              ???
0:000:x86> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0018fa24 7729b459 0x0
0018fa48 7729b42b ntdll32!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
0018fa6c 7729b3ce ntdll32!ExecuteHandler+0x24
0018faf8 77250133 ntdll32!RtlDispatchException+0x127
0018fb04 0018fb10 ntdll32!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
0018fb10 00000000 0x18fb10
```

I don't know much about programming. Can any one help to identify the problem.
You can the exe from http://files.handycafe.com/en/HandySetup_v3.exe and I get the error only when I install it as server type.

Output from `!analyze -v`:

```
0:000:x86> !analyze -v
    *******************************************************************************
    *                                                                             *
    *                        Exception Analysis                                   *
    *                                                                             *
    *******************************************************************************

    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for hndserver.exe - 

    FAULTING_IP: 
    +0
    00000000 ??              ???

    EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
    ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
       ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
      ExceptionFlags: 00000000
    NumberParameters: 2
       Parameter[0]: 0000000000000008
       Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
    Attempt to execute non-executable address 0000000000000000

    FAULTING_THREAD:  000000000000073c

    PROCESS_NAME:  hndserver.exe

    ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

    EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

    EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000008

    EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000000

    WRITE_ADDRESS:  0000000000000000 

    FOLLOWUP_IP: 
    +0
    00000000 ??              ???

    FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
    +0
    00000000 ??              ???

    NTGLOBALFLAG:  70

    APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

    APP:  hndserver.exe

    CONTEXT:  ffffffffc0000096 -- (.cxr 0xffffffffc0000096)
    Unable to read context, Win32 error 0n30

    BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL_ZEROED_STACK

    PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL

    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL

    ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

    LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000000000000 to 0000000000000000

    STACK_TEXT:  
    WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
    0018fa24 7706b459 0018fb10 0018fe3c 0018fb60 0x0
    0018fa48 7706b42b 0018fb10 0018fe3c 0018fb60 ntdll32!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
    0018fa6c 7706b3ce 0018fb10 0018fe3c 0018fb60 ntdll32!ExecuteHandler+0x24
    0018faf8 77020133 0018fb10 0018fb60 0018fb10 ntdll32!RtlDispatchException+0x127
    0018fb04 0018fb10 0018fb60 c0000096 00000000 ntdll32!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
    0018fb10 00000000 00000000 00681bc4 00000000 0x18fb10


    SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

    SYMBOL_NAME:  hndserver.exe!unknown_error_in_process

    FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

    MODULE_NAME: hndserver

    IMAGE_NAME:  hndserver.exe

    DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  2a425e19

    STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffffffc0000096 ; kb

    FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL_c0000005_hndserver.exe!unknown_error_in_process

    BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL_ZEROED_STACK_NULL_IP_hndserver.exe!unknown_error_in_process

    WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/hndserver_exe/3_3_2_1/2a425e19/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/c0000005/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

    Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: type `!analyze -v` and paste output here

Comment: The value 0x0eedfade suggests a Delphi language-level exception. I would look in event viewer or else for a stand-alone log file explaining what this exception means - and failing that contact the author.

Comment: Hi! Anything you can find from !analyze -v ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine when I installed the program as Administrator !!! Always I been trying to run the application as administrator after installing not while installing the program.